# Testing AdSense in development mode

Tags: javascript, angular, adsense

I'm developing a website which includes Google AdSense. This website is still under development and doesn't have any domain name for now. I'm trying to integrate it by giving a test URL in Google AdSense dashboard which has the dummy layout. But it is been rejected by the AdSense team by stating "Valuable Inventory: No content".

I want to know how we can test the AdSense using the test URL before the actual website goes live. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I think you need a valid URL. Google wants to make sure that your site delivers value to their customers , and isn’t just an MFA site (Made for Adsense)

Comment: So there is no way to test the website for AdSense which is under development ?

Comment: You can't get adsense until your site is released and is reviewed by adsense.